# ALB -OIDC returning 401 Authorization Required page

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, sfdc

WE have configured out ALB to authenticate with OIDC server (Salesforce). Intermitently we see after successfull login an HTML page which says 401 authorization required. Now its for sure i am not providing wrong credentails. but I do not understand why am i getting this error.

[image]

Please let me know if i need to add more information for this issue.

Comment: I had the exact same error with Azure OIDC. Turns out I provided the wrong `Issuer` endpoint. It might not be the `Issuer` in your case. You also should make sure that the ALB can reach all the endpoints, so the VPC networking must be correct.